# Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, testing, repository

My goal is to test a method of a repository interface. I had some errors when I ran this, but I fixed them (hope so). But I don't understand the following one:
[TheFullErrorStack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWXuW.png)

I have no clue whats the reason for this error because I never use `@BootstrapWith` in my test class.

This is my test class:

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@SpringBootTest
@DataJpaTest
class DepartmentRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var entityManager: TestEntityManager

    private lateinit var departmentRepository: DepartmentRepository

    @Test
    fun runFindAllByMembersContainsForNormalValuesShouldBeTrue() {

        val departmentAddress = DepartmentAddress("Musterstraße 1", "0", "Musterstadt", "Musterland")
        val cardLimits: MutableMap<JobType, Int> = mutableMapOf(Pair(JobType.EXPRESS, 1))
        val members: HashSet<Long> = mutableSetOf<Long>(1) as HashSet<Long>

        val department = Department("Test-Department", Cluster.CENTER, departmentAddress, cardLimits, true, PaymentMethods.CARD_PAYMENT_ONLY, "", "", members)
        entityManager.persist(department)
        entityManager.flush()

        val userId = 1.toLong()

        val departments = departmentRepository.findAllByMembersContains(userId)

        Assertions.assertThat(departments).isEqualTo(arrayOf(department))
    }


}
```

I dont't use `@Autowire` for the `departmentRepository`, because I would get the error that there is no bean in this interface.

Comment: Don't use both `@SpringBootTest` and `@DataJpaTest`. They are mutually exclusive (this is also what the error is, kind of, telling you). Looking at your test you only want `@DataJpaTest`, so remove `@SpringBootTest`. And add the `@Autowired` for the repository again.

Comment: How I said...When I add the `@Autowired` for the repository then I'll get an error that there is no `@Bean` in my interface `DepartmentRepository`

Comment: Have you actually read my comment? ANd the only thing you do is argue with the autowiring.

Comment: I read it, You said I should add the `@Autowired` for the Repository. And I said why this is not possible.

Comment: Anyway...When I remove `@SpringBootTest` I get the error `Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test`

Comment: If you get the error you say it does, the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class is not in the place where you should put it.

Comment: Sorry for that...But I don't know how to add a `@Bean` to an interface

Comment: You don't. As I assume it is a spring data repository, which will be auto detected **if** you have written aproper `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class and placed that in a top-level package.

Comment: Yes it is...But I still don't know why there is an error saying `Could not autowire. No beans of 'DepartmentRepository' type found. ` when I put `@Autowired` above the repository.
And I removed the `@SpringBootTest` as you said, but I still get an error: `Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test`
Can you help me with that, please?

Comment: Again, if that error is coming your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class isn't in the location as suggested by the manual and you placed it somewhere else, rendering parts of the auto-configuration useless. So either move that class to the proper place or add `@ContextConfiguration(classes = your.annotated.class)`. Which will probably also fail with another error that the repositories cannot be found (due to the structure of your project).